# LEFT JOIN a table including a SUM returns incorrect data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (orders & payments) with One To Many Relationship (Order has many payments)

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `payment_type` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
CONSTRAINT `payments_order_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`)
```

When I do a SUM() of total the values are incorrect. My current query is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(orders.created_at, '%Y-%m') AS grouped,
  SUM(orders.total) AS total,
  SUM(payments.value) AS total_payments,
  SUM(orders.total) - SUM(payments.value) AS balance,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN payments.payment_type = 0 THEN payments.value
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS card,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN payments.payment_type = 1 THEN payments.value
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS pos,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN payments.payment_type = 2 THEN payments.value
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS cash
FROM `orders` LEFT JOIN `payments` ON `orders`.`id` = `payments`.`order_id`
WHERE `orders`.`created_at` BETWEEN '1997-05-26 00:00:00' and '2024-05-26 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `grouped`
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Link of the fiddle with data:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vv3zHu6VCHNnihjszSg3ua/0

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [logically] a query is performed this way:

1. Do all the `JOINing`.
2. Do the `GROUP BY` and all aggregations like `SUM` and `COUNT`.

Hence, any COUNT or SUM on `order` will produce an inflated value because there are multiple rows due to the 1:many relation of `payments`.

The solution is to do the `SUMming` *before* `JOINing`.

Here's one way:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT order_id, 
                  SUM(...)
               FROM `order`
               WHERE ...
               GROUP BY order_id ) AS o2
    JOIN payments AS p  ON p.order_id = o2.order_id
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
```